# Why does Stack Overflow's code snippet show a different result compared with a normal editor?

Tags: discussion, design, stack-snippets

Today, when I was answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241794/css-skew-angle-align-with-3-rows/), I observed that the result from the code snippet Stack Overflow give us is different from other editors. For example, [this](https://c.runoob.com/front-end/61/) and [this](https://htmledit.squarefree.com/) both shows the right result, while Stack Overflow's result is incorrect. I have already checked the website code, but it is just an iframe, so it should get the same answer.

[image: The result on Stack Overflow]
[image: The result on another website]

Here is the code:

```html
<title>测试</title>
<style type="text/css">
.RightAngleTrapezoid {
 width:120px;height:0;margin:100px auto;
 border-right:15px solid transparent;
 border-top:15px solid;
  position:absolute;
}
</style>
<button onclick="ChangeSize()">
  Test To change size
</button>
<input id="time" value="3">
<div id="Flag" style="transform:scale(0.5,1.1)">
<div id="UpPosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:0;width:250"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:yellow;transform:rotate(180deg);left:250;top:0;width:180;"></div>
</div>

<div id="MiddlePosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:blue;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:15;width:170;border-right:80px solid transparent;border-top:90px solid"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(180deg);left:170;top:15;width:195;border-right:80px solid transparent;border-top:90px solid"></div>
</div>

<div id="DownPosition">
  <div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:red;transform:rotate(360deg);left:0;top:105;width:155"></div>
<div class="RightAngleTrapezoid" style="color:yellow;transform:rotate(180deg);left:155;top:105;width:275;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function ChangeSize(){
var element = document.getElementById("Flag");
  var ho = 0.5;
  var ve = 1.1;
  var times = document.getElementById("time").value;
  console.log(element);
element.setAttribute("style", "transform:scale("+ho * times + ","+ve * times + ");");
}
</script>
```

I wonder why it will show different answers in Stack Overflow's code snippet.

Comment: You're using CSS properties without units (eg `width: 155;`). Therefore, the discussion should be how browsers fallback, if they do, and what unit (px?) should they use to fallback. However, in my opinion, you can only compare SO snippet with those other pages once you have an HTML with proper CSS units.